# Interpolating new data points before curve fit

Tags: regression, variance, bias, interpolation

In a hypothetical situation with sparse experimental data, the researchers use interpolation (linear or cubic splines) between the points to generate more data before applying modeling (eg GLMs) and numerical techniques (eg finite difference). How would this affect the final output? Does it bias it in a known direction? My gut says it would artificially lower the standard errors but I'm not sure by how much

Comment: If the points that you interpolate between are widely spread and you use linear interpolation when the curve is quadratic the mean square error of the fit could increase.

Comment: Those researchers are not "generating more data": they are merely applying a complex *ad hoc* analysis to the data they have.  How it affects the results depends on what the "output" is and what the details of the "modeling" might be. @Michael provides a good example demonstrating that the standard errors could be inflated in some cases.

Comment: @whuber I agree re: "generating more data"; perhaps I should have put that in quotes. This (hypothetical) procedure was described to me by a colleague who seemed to think it was standard practice. Intuitively it felt wrong to me but I can't figure out how or if it affects the predictions in any consistent manner. A further complication is the submission of this work doesn't usually involve descriptions of error so the primary concern is the mean prediction.

Comment: It doesn't add information. Depending on how it's used it may possibly be a very bad idea, potentially leading (among other things) to an erroneous impression of statistical significance where there is none. But some uses may be mostly harmless-- it depends on what is done.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see anything good in doing this. The obvious alternative is to fit a model that assumes this type of smooth  curve and that's the appropriate way of doing this.

Adding artificial extra points at best leads to wrong SEs, CIs without nominal coverage and invalid p-values - and that's when the true curve is from the class of piecewise functions used for interpolation with nothing "interesting" happening in the unobserved segments of the curve. The interpolation will overfit each data point and gives a too high mean squared error.

If the true curve is different, then all bets are off and things can get more or less arbitrarily bad.

In short, it's a very inappropriate thing to do.